# SMTP authentication with .NET fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtpclient

Hello i am having some problems sending mails thoug my site.

I keep getting the error

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: SMTP authentication is required.

My Web.config have

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp from="XXXX@XXXXX.XX">
            <network host="mail.XXXXX.XX" port="25" userName="XXXX@XXXXX.XX" password="XXXXXXXX" defaultCredentials="true" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

And my code

```
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress("XXXX@XXXXX.XX");
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(split[0]));
            message.Subject = split[1];
            message.Body = ContactUsBody(model);
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Send(message);
```

It throws the error on client.Send(message), i think that for some reason it dose not use the password and username from the config.
I have tried logging on to the email account though thunderbird and have no problems sending or receiving mails there.
What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not use the credentials that you've provided because you have set it to use default credentials.

Try this:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp from="XXXX@XXXXX.XX" deliveryMethod="network">
            <network host="mail.XXXXX.XX" port="25" userName="XXXX@XXXXX.XX" password="XXXXXXXX" defaultCredentials="false" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: That did not help :( same problem, i have tripelt checked the username and password and they are not wrong.